Is the Consumer Key in Oauth1.0 sensible
I'm making requests using postman to an API that authorizes the requests with the OAuth 1.0 protocol.
Postman requires 4 token inputs 

Token Secret
Access Token
Consumer Secret
Consumer Key

I understand the first 3 are sensible, but my question is, is the consumer Key also sensible? From what I read from the Oauth 1.0 RFC, the consumer Key it is used by the consumer to identify itself with to the Service provider but the token itself does not provide any permissions, am I wrong?
Thanks!

What do you mean with 'sensible'  here? Did you mean sensitive? Even then your question is confusing.

Sorry, I meant sensitive
